# Is there Match Or Exception Regex in .NET

Tags: c#, regex, exception

I would like to do something like the below but throw an exception because there is no match. Is that possible?

```
var val = Regex.Match("nomatchplz", "notgoingtomatch(.*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't .Value already throw a NullReferenceException because Group[1] is false? Or is Group[1] already cause an ArgumentOutOfRangeException because the Indexer can't be resolved?

Comment: Bizarrely, no.  "If groupnum is not the index of a member of the collection, or if groupnum is the index of a capturing group that has not been matched in the input string, the method returns a Group object whose Group.Success property is false and whose Group.Value property is String.Empty."

Comment: Thats what i would like but it returns "" if the match doesnt exist. Regardless of success or not. I wouldnt mind so much if an exception was thrown on pattern failure. Matthew +1

Comment: @acid, why did you accept this?  It's not correct.  I would accept Sjuul's.

Comment: Sjuul told me what i already knew. I wanted a one line function call. I accepted this because reading any of the first two comment says no, it doesnt and you cant. -edit- also i upvoted the comment instead of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The Regex.Match function returns a Match object. It has the functionality you're looking for. But you should throw the exception yourself

```
    Match x = Regex.Match("","");
    if (!x.Success)
    {
        throw new Exception("My message");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check the result of the regex and throw if no matches are found.  Unless I'm misunderstanding?